# How about Apple’s enterprise distribution iOS apps

Tags: ios, enterprise

I have a iOS app use the account A.

My client gave me an enterprise account B for  In-House distribution.

I'm not allowed to revoke their existing certificates and they do not provide .p12 and .developerprofile.

I called the apple center and they told me `NO .P12 key can also publish procedures` but did not told me how to do.

My E-mail have joined the team,
I create a new app id and a provisioning profiles but the  provisioning profiles is error in my Xcode.

> error message:The private key for "XXX" is not installed on this Mac.

My question:
I just want to release `.ipa` for in-house type how to do？
thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to p12 (private key) form the client or revoke the current profile. There is not other option. Do not revoke any provisioning profiles for current apps since they may used.

Also explain to the client what you are doing and the consequences that it may have, if they are not able to provide you with the necessary certificates.

Answer (score 0):

You generate a Certificate Sign Request (CSR) from your Keychain, login to your developer account and choose your client's team.

You then create an enterprise certificate which will have to be approved by your client's team manager. Once that is done you will be able to download it and install it on your keychain.

After that generate a provisioning profile for the app you want to distribute, download and install it on Xcode.

Build your app with this certificate and save the IPA for enterprise distribution.

Comment: 'You then create an enterprise certificate ' which one?iOS Distribution?It already exists.

Comment: Sorry I missed the part where you said you can't revoke the certificate. This answer may lead you in the right direction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449087/how-do-i-produce-an-ios-release-build-that-my-client-can-sign-on-their-end/11038792#11038792

Comment: So unfortunately there is no other way for you to do this other than getting the p12 from the client or revoke the existing certificate (as per @rckoenes answer above).

Comment: Apple Developer Technical Support:'In order to distribute an iOS Enterprise (In-House) app on the behalf of a client for which you have developed the app, the client must transfer the developer profile (which includes Enterprise distribution certificate and its private key) to the third party developing the internal use application.'